# Read customized message when content updates for aria-live

Tags: accessibility, uiaccessibility, aria-live

If I have an element that has the aria-live='polite', but I don't want the screen reader to reads the updated content, but a customized message I provide, is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding content to a live region when you don't want it announced goes against the design of the [ARIA live region specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#attrs_liveregions), so I'd encourage you to think this through before proceeding with whatever you're doing here, but for purposes of this question I'm going to focus purely on what is and isn't technically possible.

You could, in theory, add `aria-hidden="true"` to the content in the live region that you don't want announced. This will prevent this section of the DOM from being exposed to the accessibility tree in the browser. At the same time, this content will be visible to sighted visitors.

On the flipside, you can add content to a live region that isn't visible to sighted users. This would be the "custom message" that you describe. The usual technique for this would be to [position the content off-screen using CSS](https://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/#techniques).

Comment: If I always want the screen reader to reads the same message in the hidden field whenever a variable gets change, but I don't want to read the updated value. What is the best way to do? For example: <div aria-live='polite' className={cx('hidden-field')}><span>Some value updated</span></div>. How should I force the span to rerender if a variable changed?

Comment: You would likely need to remove the "custom message" and re-add it through scripting. This element would need to be positioned off-screen using CSS. As a caveat, I've found that for live regions to work correctly, it's best have any elements added/removed be direct children of the live region. If you have any wrapper divs, it can cause things to not work in some screen readers.

Comment: I am using react and I use useEffect to detect the change of the variable. Each time the variable changes, I remove the span inside the div and add the span back to the div, but screen reader never reads anything. Do you have any recommendations? If I don't remove the span from the div, the screen reader reads my message, but I do need to remove the existing message. I guess maybe remove and add happens consecutively in the call and aria-live thinks there is no difference before and after in the dom tree?

Comment: Can you post a working code sample (e.g. through JSFiddle, Codepen, etc.)? This would be very helpful in troubleshooting your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Please find my code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-frost-yprot . I used a count variable to mimic the change of my variable. How can I make it announce customized message when count changed?

Comment: In addition, I don't want the screen reader to read anything in the first render. How to achieve that?

Comment: I'm not proficient in React, and your example code doesn't seem to be updating the live region. So, I've created my own example using vanilla JS here: https://jsfiddle.net/sukop8h1/1/  If you test this using a screen reader, you should see that the visual text and the text announced by the screen reader are different. This should hopefully be enough to get you started in the right direction.